# Unsigned Long compared to a negative value in existing library

Tags: c, coverity

While exploring some C code, I found a less than to zero comparison using an unsigned long variable. What is the purpose of this? Redundancy?  When you assign a negative value to a UL it will be a large positive number, hence this statement will always be false.

In other parts of the code, the variable daeSleep is assigned a -1, but it is just FFFF FFFF not a number less than 0. Coverity does not like this comparison because it is always false no matter what.

```
unsigned long daeSleep;
if(daeSleep < 0)
    daeSleep = 0;
```

Comment: my compiler warns me when I do that, I'm sure the compiler optimizes the whole `if` block out. I hope this isn't the code verbatim.. `daeSleep` is uninitialized in your example, so even if it was signed this would be UB.

Comment: Can you ask the author of the code? Looks plain wrong to me.

Comment: Yep, looks like a bug.

Comment: Is it hand-written code or may it be code generated by some code generator (e.g. code generated from some graphical model)?

Comment: the author first wanted to assign 0 for every negative value, then he learned about "unsigned". But he forgot to change that condition. Just chill, there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Not necessarily a bug, maybe just a useless check.

Answer (score -1):

Or he shows off,like while (1) or so,he chose that condition that is always false to manipulate loops and ifs